# GTK3 - Python Treeview Fixed Height Mode Property Problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, treeview, gtk, gtk3

I have a GTK3 GUI called by using Python 3. There is a treeview on the GUI and I add a large data to the treeview. To be able to increase the performance, I changed `fixed-height-mode` property to `True` but it gives the following output:

```
(test.py:6423): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 09:49:48.375: gtk_tree_view_insert_column: assertion 'gtk_tree_view_column_get_sizing (column) == GTK_TREE_VIEW_COLUMN_FIXED' failed

(test.py:6423): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 09:49:48.375: gtk_tree_view_insert_column: assertion 'gtk_tree_view_column_get_sizing (column) == GTK_TREE_VIEW_COLUMN_FIXED' failed

(test.py:6423): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 09:49:48.375: gtk_tree_view_insert_column: assertion 'gtk_tree_view_column_get_sizing (column) == GTK_TREE_VIEW_COLUMN_FIXED' failed

(test.py:6423): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 09:49:48.376: gtk_tree_view_insert_column: assertion 'gtk_tree_view_column_get_sizing (column) == GTK_TREE_VIEW_COLUMN_FIXED' failed

(test.py:6423): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 09:49:48.376: gtk_tree_view_insert_column: assertion 'gtk_tree_view_column_get_sizing (column) == GTK_TREE_VIEW_COLUMN_FIXED' failed

(test.py:6423): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 09:49:48.377: gtk_tree_view_insert_column: assertion 'gtk_tree_view_column_get_sizing (column) == GTK_TREE_VIEW_COLUMN_FIXED' failed
```

What is the solution to fix this problem?

**Note:** I am using treeview with treestore to add the data. `set_headers_clickable`, `set_headers_visible`, `set_search_column` are also used.

Here is the information about [fixed_height_mode](https://docs.huihoo.com/pygtk/2.0-tutorial/sec-TreeModelInterface.html) (GTK2, but GTK3 also suports this feature. There is an option for it on Glade Designer interface.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

> This inserts the column into the self at position. If position is -1, then the column is inserted at the end. If self has “fixed_height” mode enabled, then **column must have its “sizing” property set to be Gtk.TreeViewColumnSizing.FIXED.**

This is from [treeview.insert_column](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/TreeView.html#Gtk.TreeView.insert_column)

BTW, I strongly recommend using up-to-date documentation for your version of toolkit. Use GTK2 tutorials just to get an overview, but switch to GTK3 docs ASAP.

Comment: It fixed my problem.